# If url do something

Tags: templating

I am trying to simply change a `nav` element if one homepage and another if on the blog or another page.

I can the following to display if I set the following statement to `!=`

```
{% if craft.request.getUrl() == 'http://testsite.com/page/' %}
    {{siteUrl}}
{% endif %}
```

However I can't figure out what that is returning as no matter what I put it doesn't work.

Comment: You can always see what a variable returns by outputting it like so {{ craft.request.getUrl() }}

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I'd use segments for that. Something like:

```
{% if craft.request.lastSegment == "page" %}
   do something
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if craft.request.segments(1) == "page" %}
   do something
{% endif %}
```

These days, though, when not making a dynamic nav, I tend to pass a variable to my extended layouts or nav include. I find it much more flexible / robust than just relying on URL structures or segments.

In child template

```
{% set currentNav = "home" %}
```

or

```
{% include 'includes/_nav' with {'currentNav':'home'} %}
```

In include or extended layout

```
{% if currentNav == "home" %}
   do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That 2nd example should read segment, not segments...

Comment: Hey Anna, not sure about this. Here is what the doc says: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#segments

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Not sure either - segmentS wasn't working for me, but segment was. Go figure :P

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the options Jerome mentioned, you can also test for the Entry Type, which typically would be different for homepage vs blog, etc.

```
{% if entry.type == 'home' %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Switch also works well here.

```
{% switch entry.type %}
   {% case 'home' %}
   ...
   {% case 'blog' %}
   ...
   {% default %}
   ...
{% endswitch %}
```